# Choose entire list if random sample size is too large

Tags: python

In Python, we can randomly sample from a list as so:

```
>>> import random
>>> l = [1,2,3]
>>> random.sample(l,2)
[2, 3]
```

However, if the sample size is larger than the list, it returns an error:

```
>>> random.sample(l,4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/random.py", line 315, in sample
    raise ValueError("Sample larger than population")
ValueError: Sample larger than population
```

Is there an option that will allow `random.sample` to choose the entire list if the sample size is larger than the list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no such option (see `help(random.sample)`), but you can always control what you pass:

```
random.sample(l, min(len(l),4))
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

something like:

```
random.sample(l) if len(l)<4 else random.sample(l, 4)
```

Comment: `random(l,...)` also reshuffles the list, but your expression does not.

Comment: There's no requirement to shuffle but it can be easily achieved - updated.